# if en procedimientos almacenados

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedure

lo que pasa es que tengo en mi pagina web un formulario con tres campos, "buscar, filtrar por estado, filtrar por empresa"

bien cada uno de ellos me tiene que mandar una consulta, por ejemplo
si solo busca por el input 'buscar' me da una determinada consulta, si busca por 'filtrar por estado' me da otra consulta y así.

Si funciona la lógica que yo hice, pero fueron muchas líneas de código, entonces me plantee la idea de crear un procedimiento almacenado para que me devuelva una sola consulta dependiendo lo que le pase, esto lo hice con los if anidados, pero tengo un error

```
SELECT * FROM oferta_trabajo  as oft 
    LEFT JOIN usuario_empresa as usuEm 
    ON usuEm.id_usuario_empresa = oft.fk_id_usuario_empresa 
    LEFT JOIN datos_empresa as dt 
    ON usuEm.id_usuario_empresa = dt.fk_id_usuario_empresa 
    WHERE   oft.categoria_carrera = carrera
    AND 

    #cuando solo se busca por oferta
    if( buscar != '' &&  filtrarEstado = '' && filtrarEmpresa = '', oft.puesto LIKE concat('%', buscar, '%' ), 
        
        #cuando solo se busca por estado de empleo
        if(filtrarEstado != '' &&  buscar = '' && filtrarEmpresa = '', oft.tipo_empleo LIKE concat('%', filtrarEstado, '%' ), 
            
            #cuando solo se busca por empresa
            if(filtrarEmpresa != '' &&  buscar = '' && filtrarEstado = '', dt.nombre LIKE concat('%', buscar, '%' ),
            
                #cuando se busca por oferta y se filtra por estado
                if(buscar != '' &&  filtrarEstado != '' && filtrarEmpresa = '', ( oft.puesto LIKE concat('%', buscar, '%' ) AND oft.tipo_empleo LIKE concat('%', filtrarEstado, '%' ) ), '')
            )
        ) 
    )
    
    ORDER BY id_oferta_trabajo DESC 
    LIMIT desde, limite;
```

y es que cuando le paso el parámetro de 'buscar' y el de 'filtrar estado' no me hace la búsqueda, y ya comprobé que si entra en ese if, pero yo creo que no me consulta porque son dos parámetros que me retorna por así decirlo

```
if(buscar != '' &&  filtrarEstado != '' && filtrarEmpresa = '', ( oft.puesto LIKE concat('%', buscar, '%' ) AND oft.tipo_empleo LIKE concat('%', filtrarEstado, '%' ) ), '')
```

en esa parte no me coge la sentencia, pero si le borro la parte después de el AND si me coge la sentencia, entonces no se como le haría para que me coja la sentencia de esa estructura, no se si me esplique bien

Comment: Saludos. En lugar de `IF` usa `CASE...WHEN...THEN...ELSE....END`.

Answer (score 0):

al parecer ya lo resolvi, el problema era que en el LIMIT le estaba poniendo un limite desde 1 a 10
lo que me hacia que si encontraba solo una fila no me la mostrara, le cambie el limite de 0 a 10 y ahora ya funciona, los if anidados estaban bien hechos, que alegria :)